# How to do error handling in Liquibase for unset dynamic properties in changelog?

Tags: xml, database, undefined, liquibase

In our **changelog-master.xml** file we have a list of the changesets we want to apply to the DB schema. For example:

```
<changeSet author="test" id="01-update" runOnChange="true">
        <update tableName="system_attributes">
            <column name="value" value="${WebServiceURL}" />
            <where>key='WebServiceURL'</where>
        </update>
</changeSet>
```

Our dynamic properties are then defined in our **changelog.xml** file:

```
<!-- FROM TABLE SYSTEM_ATTRIBUTES -->
<property name="WebServiceURL" value="https://localhost/webService/" /> 
    ...
```

With that in mind, liquibase will then replace the `${WebServiceURL}` statement with `https://localhost/webService/` when the tool is run. This works fine. However, how do we do error handling when the property `${WebServiceURL}` is undefined in the **changelog.xml** file?

I need it to either do a transactional rollback, or throw some sort of error message and an exit of liquibase when the **changelog-master.xml** tries to access an undefined variable.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such feature. A workaround could be to add a "not null" or "not empty" constraint on this column.